# Skipping the second automatically generated quote in QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, navigation, qt-creator

When I begin my program and type

```
cout << "
```

it automatically puts the closing quote (`""`) and places the cursor in the middle, which is nice; however, I can't seem to find a way to get past the second one without having to move my hand to use the arrow keys, use the mouse, or put another `"` manually, which defeats the purpose.

My buddy said <kbd>tab</kbd> should skip it, but it just does an indent.

Comment: I do not understand. Why would you jump at the end without editing? If you edit in order, then you will be almost at the end after all? What are you trying to achieve again? Also, what is wrong about the usual end, or even right arrow in this special case?

Comment: You want to move past the `"` without using the keyboard OR mouse? Another keyboard option: `END` should work. Personally, I just type another `"`.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry if this sounds disappointing, but there is no other way than using:

a) arrow key.

b) end button on the keyboard in the regular way.

c) typing another quote.

Basically what you also mentioned yourself in the question. Even if the tab was working, you would not spare anything as you already have at least two keys with which you get over.

Comment: I don't agree with your last sentence. I can reach the tab key without moving my hands away from starting position. This doesn't apply for arrow nor end key. For me, usually, typing the quotation marks anyway is the way to go. I would heavily prefer tab-key though.